# Hide Floating Action Button when list can't be scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use a Floating Action Button in my project Android, and I hide it when the list scrolls to the bottom and I shows when it scrolls to the top, through the implementation of a OnScrollListener on my Recyclerview.

```
 @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        boolean isSignificantDelta = Math.abs(dy) > mScrollThreshold;
        if (isSignificantDelta) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                onScrollUp();
            } else {
                onScrollDown();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I would like to hide this fab when my list is not scrollable, for that my last element is completely visible.

Scrolled's method is not called when my list is empty, or contains few items and is not scrollable because of his size.

Do you have a tip to call this method because this seems be my solution to do what I want to do ?

Comment: Maybe you can make use of [`CoordinatorLayout`'s `Behavior`s](https://github.com/newfivefour/BlogPosts/blob/master/android-coordinatorlayout-scrolling-hide-fab-behavior.md)?

Comment: @azizbekian With a CoordinatorLayout, How can I hide my FAB when he's overlapping the last item of my list, which is not scrollable (not enough elements in the list).

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
public abstract class HideShowScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

private static final int HIDE_THRESHOLD = 20;
private int scrolledDistance = 0;
private boolean controlsVisible = true;

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    if (scrolledDistance > HIDE_THRESHOLD && controlsVisible) {
        onHide();
        controlsVisible = false;
        scrolledDistance = 0;
    } else if (scrolledDistance < -HIDE_THRESHOLD && !controlsVisible) {
        onShow();
        controlsVisible = true;
        scrolledDistance = 0;
    }

    if ((controlsVisible && dy > 0) || (!controlsVisible && dy < 0)) {
        scrolledDistance += dy;
    }
}

public abstract void onHide();

public abstract void onShow();
}
```

in your activity define below code,
here floatingAdd is floating button.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HideShowScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            floatingAdd.animate().setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).scaleX(0).scaleY(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            floatingAdd.animate().setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).scaleX(1).scaleY(1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm already using this implementation but onScrolled is not called when my list only contains few items.

Comment: Please review my question. I would like to hide the FAB but onScrolled is not called so I don't know how i can do.

Comment: just do one thing when setVisibility of Floating button Gone and when your list is scrolling then set it to Visible/Gone.

Comment: The problem is that when my list contains few elements without been scrollable, the fab is above the last element, and onScrolled is not called

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a right way to do, but I didn't found any better solution.

In `getItemCount` method I return `array.size()+2` so recycler view creates two more items (that's just the right amount for me, you might need another number). In `onCreateViewHolder` method I check at what position view should be created. And if it's out of bounds of my array of items - I just disable all widgets inside (buttons, editTexts etc.) and set its visibility to invisible (not gone since I need it to occupy some space).
I also have callback `onItemMove` that is called when user reorders items with drag. Inside that I check that new position is not out of bounds of my array. Of course drag is disabled for the last two items.

So as I said, this is a workaround, but a very simple one. And I didn't notice any downsides of it. Hope this helps!